# No shipping info is collected

Tags: commerce

Update: Well, now it is showing, but we're still running into another error. Will post in a new thread.

I've got our store set up with products that are all shippable.

There is one Product variation type. It is set to have dimensions and be shippable.

It has one shipping method - Free shipping. All orders get free shipping. So that is set up on the shipping methods page.

Under order types, we only have one type. The workflow is "Fulfillment". Shipping is enabled. The only type available is selected. Then under the flow, Shipping is selected.

Shipping flow:

Login:
Login or continue as guest

Order information:
Contact information
Shipping information
Payment information

Review:
Review

When you run through an order, it goes straight to the Review page - nothing for shipping.

I've run through everything multiple times and can't seem to find what I'm missing.